# Use a specific version of Matplotlib in a Single Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, version, libraries

I am trying to use an older version of Python's matplotlib (and other packages/libraries too) for compatibility purposes in a Jupyter notebook. Is it possible to specify certain package versions in a notebook to be used *only* for that notebook (not other ones)? I don't want to change my global settings. If so, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: It's more common to think about it as a project-wide basis; however, the entire breadth of that project could be one notebook. One option would be to make a conda or virtual environment where you work on the project. This would be separate from your default installation. Using the Anaconda distribution makes this easy. There are other virtual environment options that are Python-centric. One of the many other options is to make a container (Docker is common) where you work on this project and control the backing environment. If this is something that doesn't take vast amounts of resources ...

Comment: <continued> you can use the MyBinder service to serve the environment inside a temporary remote server session connected to without login. You use simple configuration files to list the packages and specify versions, example `requirements.txt` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) or `environment.yml` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda). You can customize a repository (not restricted to GitHub) that the service uses to launch a session with your environment. It uses Docker but you don't need to know Docker at all as you really don't see it.

Comment: You may be interested in [this discussion](https://twitter.com/choldgraf/status/1595356915483262984), too. It's not per notebook, but gets at not messing with global settings. Especially about 'JupySpace'.